# angularjs - use injected service to get properties

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a basic calculator app on jsfiddle to get some more experience with angular and I wanted to know if injected services can be used like objects to get properties. For example:

```
angular.module('CalcApp', [])
.controller('CalcVm', CalcVm)
.service('MathOperations', MathOperations);

angular.$inject = ['MathOperations'];
function CalcVm(MathOperations) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.xyz = '';
 //code
}

function MathOperations() {
 var addOp = '+';
 var subtractOp = '-';
 //etc..
}
```

is it possible to do this in the view:

```
<div ng-controller='CalcVm as calcVm'>
   <button>{{calcVm.MathOperations.addOp}}</button>
</div>
```

should I bind the service to a variable in the controller?

```
function CalcVm(MathOperations) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.xyz = '';
 vm.MathOperations = MathOperations;
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've been experimenting with this and I've figured it out.

what worked was the following:

```
angular.module('CalcApp', [])
.controller('CalcVm', CalcVm)
.service('MathOperations', MathOperations);

angular.$inject = ['MathOperations'];
function CalcVm(MathOperations) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.MathOperations = MathOperations;
 //more code
}

function MathOperations() {
 this.addOp = '+';
 this.subtractOp = '-';
 //etc..
}
```

notice that I've used the keyword `this` in the service and I've assigned the injected service to a variable in my controller.

I'm not sure if this is good or bad practice and if anyone knows please edit this answer below the line with further info.

---